# Lodash finding difference between JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, json, lodash, array-difference

Using lodash for finding difference:

c1Arr is:

```
[ { varName: 'city', varValue: 'cccccccc' },
  { varName: 'country', varValue: 'dddddddd' }
 ]
```

c2Arr is:

```
[ { varName: 'abc', varValue: 'aaa' },
  { varName: 'city', varValue: 'cccccccc' },
  { varName: 'country', varValue: 'dddddddd' }
 ]
```

Executing the following code

```
    var dArr = _.difference(c2Arr, c1Arr);
    console.log(dArr);
```

Why don't I get the result :

```
[ { varName: 'abc', varValue: 'aaa' }]
```

Instead I get (i.e. c2Arr)

```
[ { varName: 'abc', varValue: 'aaa' },
  { varName: 'city', varValue: 'cccccccc' },
  { varName: 'country', varValue: 'dddddddd' }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the `comparator` function, since the elements are object.

Try this,

```
_.differenceWith(c2Arr, c1Arr, _.isEqual);
```

```js
var c1Arr = [{
  varName: 'city',
  varValue: 'cccccccc'
}, {
  varName: 'country',
  varValue: 'dddddddd'
}]

var c2Arr = [{
  varName: 'abc',
  varValue: 'aaa'
}, {
  varName: 'city',
  varValue: 'cccccccc'
}, {
  varName: 'country',
  varValue: 'dddddddd'
}]

var dArr = _.differenceWith(c2Arr, c1Arr, _.isEqual);
console.log(dArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried, but still the same result. :-(

Comment: Thanks, this works now. will fix my main program. :-)

Comment: @RaR nice, when I run this it says `_.differenceWith` is not a function, I have Lodash installed